# ORA-06561 while executing PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have this procedure:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE P_P2
IS
v_str varchar2(1000);
v_file_name varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
P_P1(v_str, 'EXPORT_CSV',v_file_name);
v_str := 'select * from H----)';
v_file_name :=  'H_'||to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY')||'.csv';
END;
```

I am getting error "ORA-06561: given statement is not supported by package DBMS_SQL" when I execute it:

```
Error starting at line : 165 in command -
exec P_P1
Error report - 
ORA-06561: given statement is not supported by package DBMS_SQL
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1120
ORA-06512: at "BIDB.P_P1", line 40
ORA-06512: at "BIDB.P_P2", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 1
06561. 00000 -  "given statement is not supported by package DBMS_SQL"
*Cause:    Attempting to parse an unsupported statement using procedure
           PARSE provided by package DBMS_SQL.
*Action:   Only statements which begin with SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE,
           LOCK, BEGIN, DECLARE or << (PL/SQL label delimiter) are supported.
```

I cannot see why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is coming from a call made at "BIDB.P_P1" line 40, and you haven't shown us that procedure. You also seem to be exec'ing `P_P1` directly, not via `P_P2`, which is  bit confusing as that doesn't seem to be what the error is  saying.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown what `P_P1` is doing, but from what you have shown, your `P_P2` procedure may just be calling it too early; you have a call to `P_P1` which uses `v_str` as a parameter, but it's null at that point - you set it *after* the call that uses it.

That means that somewhere in `P_P1` you are probably ending up doing the equivalent of:

```
 dbms_sql.parse(c, null, dbms_sql.native);
```

which throws the error you are seeing. You're doing the same with `v_filename`, which will presumably cause other issues.

So for a start, swap those lines around so the procedure is called last:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE P_P2
IS
  v_str varchar2(1000);
  v_file_name varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
  v_str := 'select * from H----)';
  v_file_name :=  'H_'||to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY')||'.csv';
  -- call this AFTER populating the variables
  P_P1(v_str, 'EXPORT_CSV',v_file_name);
END;
/
```

You may have other problems of course - the table name looks odd, both because of the dashes and the closing parenthesis; but you may have just hidden the real name oddly. You seem to have changed the procedure names too (though inconsistently, as your `exec` seems to be calling the wrong one...).